# Can't figure out why the output is wrong

Tags: c, algorithm, function, recursion

So I've been studying recursive functions and have been trying to write codes with them. This is my code for Legendre polynomials.

The function uses this formula:
P(n)=((2n-1)/n)P(n-1)-((n-1)/n)*P(n-2)

The output I want based on the inputs of x=0.5 and n=5 is:

```
x=0.500000 n=1 P(1)=0.500000
x=0.500000 n=2 P(2)=0.250000
x=0.500000 n=3 P(3)=0.083333
x=0.500000 n=4 P(4)=-0.041667
x=0.500000 n=5 P(5)=-0.141667
```

but I keep getting the outputs of:

```
x=0.500000               n=1                              P(1)=0.000000
x=0.500000               n=2                              P(2)=-0.500000
x=0.500000               n=3                              P(3)=-0.833333
x=0.500000               n=4                              P(4)=-1.083333
x=0.500000               n=5                              P(5)=-1.283333
```

I can't seem to figure out the problem. I tried to re-write the formula in the function. Maybe it has something to do with the for loop?

```
#include <stdio.h>

float Legen_Poly(n,x){
if (n==0)
    return 1;
else if (n==1)
    return x;
else{
    return ((2*n-1)*Legen_Poly(n-1,x)-(n-1)*Legen_Poly(n-2,x))/n;
}}

int main(){
  float x ,a;
  int cntrl_val=0,n;


while(cntrl_val==0){
printf("\nPlease enter x [-1,1]: ");
scanf("%f",&x);
if (x>1 || x<-1)
  printf("\nThis x value is not valid!");

else{
  printf("\nPlease enter n= ");
  scanf("%d",&n);
  if (n<0)
    printf("\nThis n value is not valid!");
  else
    cntrl_val=1;
    printf("\nThe first %d are as follows",n);
    for(int count=0;count<n;count++){
      a=Legen_Poly(1+count,x);
      printf("\nx=%f",x);printf("               n=%d",1+count);printf("                              P(%d)=%f",1+count,a);

    }}}}
```

Comment: `float Legen_Poly(n,x)` will be assumed to take `int` arguments. Please define them explicitly, for exmple `float Legen_Poly(int n, float x)`. The compiler warning *'return': conversion from 'int' to 'float', possible loss of data* shows the function isn't computing with `float` values.

Comment: Your Legendre recursive formula is wrong. The first term must be mulitplied by `x`:  `P(n)=((2n-1)/n)P(n-1)*x - ((n-1)/n)*P(n-2)`

Comment: ...and the value of `float x` passed by `main` will be truncated to `int`.